# socket.io send data to matching socket's

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

when a user connects to my socket
I add to a session map:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      sessionMap.set(socket.id,socket);
}
```

my session Map

```
var SessionMap = {};
module.exports = {
    set: function(key,value){
        SessionMap[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key){
        return SessionMap[key]
    },
    delete: function(key){
        delete SessionMap[key]
    },
    all: function(){
        return SessionMap
    }
}
```

And also save my user socket id in a class player:

```
  socket.on('addPlayer-Queue', (result) => {
      sessionMap.set(socket.id,socket);
      queue.addPlayer(new Player({
        id: result.id,
        name: result.name,
        mmr: result.mmr
      }, socket.id));
```

And I have a function that selects two players that are connected (where I save in an array) and create a "battle" and then I wanted to send to the socket that was selected / matched for this battle 
the battle dice

This is my role that selects both players and creates a battle:

```
searching() {
    const firstPlayer = this.getRandomPlayer();

    const secondPlayer = this.players.find(
      playerTwo =>
        playerTwo.mmr < this.calculateLessThanPercentage(firstPlayer) &&
        playerTwo.mmr > this.calculateGreaterThanPercentage(firstPlayer) &&
        playerTwo.id != firstPlayer.id
    );

    if (!secondPlayer) {
      return null;
    }

    const matchedPlayers = [firstPlayer, secondPlayer];
    this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
    return new Match(matchedPlayers);
  }
}
```

And also when connecting I use a set interval to be performing this function every 1 second

But my difficulty is how I would send the data from this battle to the corresponding socket's

my relation socket with player

When a player enters my event I create a player by going through socket id
And I also make a session map of this socket
sessionMap.set(socket.id,socket);

my class player:

```
class Player {
    constructor(player,socketId) {
      this.id = player.id
      this.socketId = socketId
      this.name = player.name
      this.mmr = player.mmr
    }

  }

  module.exports = Player;
```

Comment: I think you want _emit_ : `socket.broadcast.to('ID').emit( 'send msg', {somedata : somedata_server} );` see https://www.codershood.info/2016/01/24/sending-message-specific-user-socket-io/

Comment: yess but i have problem with the logic to do this:

why do the players i have to send the emit
are within my match:

return new Match (matchedPlayers);

and then I'm having a hard time getting socket.id from these players and issuing according to socket id

Comment: you didn't make clear the relationship between socket and player objects. could you add the missing code please?

Comment: Hello updated the question
basically i pass the socket id to the player builder

and also save the socket in a session map

using socket id as key

Comment: roughly `matchedPlayers.forEach(player => sessionMap.get(player.socketid).broadcast.to(player.socketid).emit(myTag, getMyDataFor(player)))` ...that so closely looks like what you were intending that I am wondering what the problem really is

Comment: Seems to me the solution hehe i just have to know where i would put this for each

I'm in doubt if I put in my searching function checking if there are players

or put myself in the builder

could you point me to the best way?

Comment: Also create an answer for me to vote positive for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getMatchConfigurationFor = player => {
    /* configure and return the payload notifying the player of the match */
}

const configurePlayersForNewMatch = () =>  matchedPlayers.forEach(player => 
    sessionMap.get(player.socketid)
        .broadcast.to(player.socketid)
        .emit(messageTags.MATCH_CONFIGURATION, 
            getMatchConfigurationFor(player)))
```

regarding where to do this work .. the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) says that a function should have a singular clear purpose. So the *search* method should search for matching players, not configure the match. You should do this work in another function that is called while configuring the match, which itself is called after the search returns successfully. I've provided the wrapper function for that here: it is written in a fashion to expect the relevant pieces are in scope. You could rewrite it as a proper function with parameters if you prefer.

*This is a work in progress solution for Felipe, posted by request.*

Comment: Oops bro I got it

my function returns matchedPlayers

In case I would have to save this in a variable and send as parameter to ess function?

Comment: if you save the result to _matchedPlayers_ where this _fat arrow function_ is called, _matcherPlayers_ will be in scope and you don't need to rewrite it. _every variable_ in the function must also be inscope from its execution context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I don't know if I get it right, but could you check it out if this or so?

https://pastebin.com/ELytTy6q

Comment: I did a check if matchedPlayers is nonzero if it is i call my configure


I find this way of writing functions much cleaner, but I don't have much experience about it

Answer (score 0):

After a match is found, you'd probably want to emit a `MatchFound` object to both clients detailing information about the match (including information about their opponent). Once a client gets this, you can initiate anything the client needs for a match (load a level, display names, or a lobby).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need,
but my function would return an array of objects.

I am looking for the logic of how to get the socket id of players who were successful in finding a match to issue per socket

Comment: I can't imagine how I would do this from matchfound and return to the players that match

Comment: I'd put it in your `Match` constructor. Once the server does everything it needs on its side, it can send the data to to the users. You can store each player's `socket` instance inside of their respective `Player` objects and send relevant data through that.

Comment: I already store socket_id in my player

but as I send an array of players
one and two
would i have to go through the list with a for each and send?

Could you give me an example?

Another possibility could be to call a function to do this within my matchmaking function.
and then I'd pass both players id if there was a match

Comment: If you can give me an example I would be grateful I still don't know how to handle the socket part